# Мне нужно чтобы при ререндеринге страницы данные, добавленные на неё ранее сохранялись. REACT

Tags: reactjs, веб-программирование, frontend

Всем привет! Освоив азы react'a я решил сразу применить знания на практике, решил создать клон сайта https://app.todoist.com/app/today, ( todo приложение с разными страницами, проектами, разделами и т. д ). Так вот, у меня есть несколько страниц - сегодня и предстоящее, реализованных с помощью react router, допустим, если я добавляю на страницу "сегодня" несколько задач, перехожу на страницу "предстоящее", а затем обратно, то все задачи пропадают, так вот мой вопрос - что мне нужно использовать, чтобы эти задачи сохранялись? (возможно какие-то хуки ?? или redux ? ). Понимаю, возможно вопрос глупый, но прошу отнестись с пониманием.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь сохранением зафиксированных данных в одно из доступных хранилищ браузера: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB)

Comment: редакс сохранит данные сессии, нажмете f5 и все пропадет. Если локально хранить, то можно localStarage. Можно еще indexDB использовать, правда гораздо сложнее будет. Самый правильный вариант, поднять бэковую часть с БД и хранить данные там, а склиента эти данные просто запрашивать

Comment: @MoloF, благодарю за ответ

Comment: @SwaD, благодарю за ответ